# Install Android Command Line Tools with Nexus Sonatype

Tags: android, nexus

I have a Nexus Server, I'd like install Android Command Line Tools for the offline computers.

Can Nexus do this and How can I do this?

Comment: What is the relation between Nexus and Android command-line tools? Nexus does not need them and also the command-line tools don't need nexus.

Comment: Hi @Robert , I need to use Nexus server to install some packages for the offline computers.

Comment: Could you please give a more detailed example what "packages" you are talking about? Are you talking about JAR or APK files?

Comment: @Robert, I used Nexus to Install NPM, Nodejs and Appium, and now I need Install Android Command-Line Tools. I don't know whether Nexus can help me do that or not. Thanks you.

Comment: Then the answer is simple: Nexus can't help you with that. If you are on Linux check your package manager, otherwise just install Android SDK.

Comment: @Robert Ok bro, I'm looking for another solution, Thanks You.